# 1350 AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException GoogleMap

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make a google map application using v2. it works a few time but then when i make changes it give me this error "1350 AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException". After removing the changes its still give me the same error.

```
package com.adilahmedzeb;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Test extends FragmentActivity{

private GoogleMap map;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

}
}
```

Comment: Post all relevant code and logcat.

Comment: Could you give the stacktrace?